# How should I handle incorrect information given in response to my question?

Tags: support, answers, wrong-answers

I have asked the question [Why is there different behavior between these two element locator calls?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58615712/why-is-there-different-behavior-between-these-two-element-locator-calls).  I was given an answer, which I believe contains incorrect information.  I posted a comment pointing this out, including a link to official documentation which describes the behavior I have seen, and that same user posted a comment saying that documentation was incorrect.

Assuming I can prove that the answer and comment are incorrect, what should I do in this case, if anything?  I would like to minimize the chances that other people reading the answer are not misled.  The options I know of would be to comment again, downvote that answer, or to delete the question; are there any other, better options?

Comment: disengaging would probably be a good idea. You can't convince everyone.

Answer (score 10):

Here is what you should do:

1. Leave a comment explaining how/why the answer is incorrect.
2. Downvote the answer.

That's it. There's really no option 3. Don't try to flag incorrect answers for moderator attention, don't vandalize their post, don't go on a rage downvoting spree against all their other contributions, don't get into a protracted war in the comments, don't kill their dog, etc.

In the best case, you or someone else will identify the *correct* answer to the question and post it. Then, that answer will get upvoted, overshadowing the incorrect answer.

This is how Stack Overflow is designed to work.

As for [people being wrong on the Internet](https://xkcd.com/386/), well, that is an age-old problem.

Comment: You also should not upvote the answer as "thanks for your effort"... which I believe happens sometime... It's really just an easy jump from trolling by not voting on incorrect answer to trolling by upvoting bad answers...

Comment: Well, it's hard to upvote the answer as a "thanks for your effort" if you've done #2. :-)

Comment: @Cody Gray Thank you for your quick response.  I'll go with your 'should do' options.  (As an aside, do you see anything wrong with the question I've asked here?  It was downvoted within seconds of my posting it, which tells me that maybe there is a problem with it that is super obvious to people here, but I think this is my first question on Meta, so if there is something wrong, I don't know what it is.)

Comment: @Phil I see nothing wrong with your Meta question. Downvotes are thrown around quite freely on Meta; it's part of the culture. Downvotes here are often used to indicate disagreement. I *suspect* that the reason people downvoted your Meta question is because they didn't think it showed sufficient research effort. What you're asking about is a pretty fundamental part of the Stack Overflow concept, so it fell into that "super obvious" category you mentioned. But again, I wouldn't put too much stock into it. Someone downvoted my answer here, too. Your question on the main site also looks fine.

Comment: Note that deleting the question could potentially remove good answers, which is why it's not recommended (in fact, it's impossible to delete some questions for this reason sometimes).

Comment: Not only that, @Chipster, but deleting the question will prevent you from ever getting a *correct* answer.